# How to make citations appear within square brackets [ ] instead of parentheses ( )?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I'm using a [this](http://pastebin.com/S3VeavUH) freely downloadable latex class file and the style is set to `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`. But when I cite something with `\cite{}` I get it inside ().

For example I get it as `abc et al. (1)` but what I want to get is `abc et al. [1]`.

Please tell me how to get my citations inside [ ] ?

Comment: I found the line 50: `\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}` It is possible that "round" makes the trouble

Comment: The class is meant for submission to IEEE conferences. So the output is like *they* want.

Comment: @egreg no this is a thesis template. And even in IEEE papers I haven't seen citing with parenthesis, it's using [].

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can simply say

```
\setcitestyle{square}
```

in your document preamble (see `natbib` documentation, section 2.9).

However, if you're using the class for a submission to an IEEE conference, leave as they want.

Comment: I have also the same problem, I want to use citation with square. I have set natbib=true, but when I write "\setcitestyle{square}", it comes out error "! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setcitestyle
l.20 \setcitestyle". Could you have a look? Thank you .http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342866/how-to-customize-citation-style-and-references

Answer (score 18):

The reason why you are getting citation numbers inside parentheses instead of square brackets is that in the class file you use, the package `natbib` is loaded with the option `round`, see line 51:

```
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
```

Just replace this line with

```
\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
```

save your class file, compile your `.tex` file and you should get square brackets. Alternatively, simply adding `\setcitestyle{square}` in the preamble of your document without modifying the class file itself should work.

Note, however, that you may also have to edit the bibliographic style to change the style of the bibliographic number (at present, is it enclosed by parentheses or square brackets?) for each item in the Bibliography section.

Comment: There's no need to modify the class

Comment: should be \setcitestyle{square}? :)

Comment: How the numbers appear in the bibliography is not governed by the `.bst` file, but by the LaTeX command `\bibitem`. There will be square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

To complement egreg's answer, class files (like for the journal Annual Review) can set the open and close characters at `\begin{document}`. In that case,
`\setcitestyle{square}`
only works if it comes *after* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Why would this be the case? Could you be using a specific document class? Can you provide example code (in minimal form) that replicates this?

Comment: @Werner, this is when using the class file for the journal Annual Reviews. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\setcitestyle{square}
```

Output:

[x]

x denotes the number of the reference.

Comment: You could probably combine them - `\setcitestyle{numbers,square}`.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: Strange how this is the way its provided in the [`natbib`](//ctan.org/pkg/natbib) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/natbib); see section **2.9 Selecting Citation Punctuation**: "...the `\setcitestyle` command, which takes as argument a comma-separated list of keywords."