# How to set the biblabel in parenthesis using achemso?

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I am using achemso package to write a manuscript. The final list of references appear in the following form

> 1. Nat. Nanotechnol. 2013, 8, 385–389.

However, I need it the serial number to appear within round brackets as

> (1) Nat. Nanotechnol. 2013, 8, 385–389.

Can anyone please help me with how to do that.

My working example:

```
\documentclass[journal=ancac3,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{Citation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82570/how-to-make-citations-appear-within-square-brackets-instead-of-parentheses. You might also want to look at the [cite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package

Comment: I haven't tried it, but in other classes, this might work: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{(#1)\hfill}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 1):

It is just one line you have to add. Ask your editor if this change is ok, since the defaults are preset according to the journals requirements.

[image: sazzadAchemso]

```
\documentclass[journal=ancac3,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{
    articletitle = true,
    biblabel = brackets% <--- this line
}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\title{The Wombat}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```