# How to customize citation style and references?

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I have three questions:

- how to remove the brackets in footnote?
- how to edit the reference info in order to show the full name of author/institute? (solved)
- how to show a citation as "[1]Author, book " in footcite and bibliography? I have tried \setcitestyle{square}, but it comes out error.

Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=authortitle-comp,
        natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={black},
citecolor={blue!50!black},
}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=authortitle-comp,
        natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
Author                   = {National Center for Health Statistics},
Note                     = {[Accessed on August 10, 2016]. Available on:\textcolor{blue}{http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
here is just a test . \footnote{\label{note1}\footcite{unintentional}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
here is just a test . \footnote{\label{note1}\footcite{unintentional}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: for the author: can you give an example on how an entry has to look like? "[1] Author, title" includes a large number of possibilities...

Comment: I want to ask the one in the question(name of institute), it only showed "Health Statistics" as author, but I want it to show "National Center for Health Statistics". Thank you @naphaneal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code of your example is broken (e.g. two `\documentclass`). After fixing this the problem persists, because `biblatex` tries to split the organization name *National Center for Health Statistics* at the `author` field into firstname and lastname. You can avoid this using extra braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={black},
citecolor={blue!50!black},
}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=authortitle-comp,
        natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
Author                   = {{National Center for Health Statistics}},
Note                     = {[Accessed on August 10, 2016]. Available on:\textcolor{blue}{http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
here is just a test. \footcite{unintentional}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

BTW: `\footcite` isn't made to be used inside `\footnote` but makes a footnote itself.

Generally I would suggest to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`. New `biblatex` features need `biber`. It is time to change.

To get cites with numbers in brackets you can use the `numeric` style of `biblatex`. But `\footcite` won't show the author and title in this case. [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) has already shown in [how to define such a *footcite* command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29931/9057):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}% Much better than:
% \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
% \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=numeric,
        natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}% Generally last package loaded
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={black},
citecolor={blue!50!black},
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
Author                   = {{National Center for Health Statistics}},
URL                      = {http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm},
urldate                  = {2016-08-10},
}
\end{filecontents}
% Define new \footcite like command with number and author
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
here is just a test. \footpartcite{unintentional}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This will produce:

[image: References]

[image: Footnote]

Note, I've also replaced the `Note` field by `URL` and `urldate`. See the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for more information about these and about how to customize the output of the URL date.

If you need a similar cite command, that does not create a footnote itself but can be used inside `\footnote` or somewhere else without creating a footnote just use the same definitions without the optional argument `\mkbibfootnote`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\partcites}{\partcite}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

With this you can use:

```
Test: \footnote{\label{ftn:unintentional}\partcite{unintentional}}

See footnote \ref{ftn:unintentional}.
```

To create a footnote with label.

Please read the documentation of the used commands, i.e., `\DeclareCiteCommand` in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for more information about creating new cite commands.

Comment: Thank you!I used \footnote and\footcite together, because I need to cite the same article in different places, so the first one I cite with a \footnote{\label{note1}\footcite{unintentional}}, later I can refer to  it with \footnoteref{note1}. I do need both footcite and also reference function from footnote, do you have a better solution for this?How can I use labelname from your solution? I have tried your solution but it doesn´t create bibliography, and in footpartcite, it only showed "1 unintentional". Why doesn´t it reproduce the same result as what you´ve showed in your answer?

Comment: @Vivian: Have you tried exactly my example or something different? Once more: You should not use `\footcite` inside `\footnote`. Use either `\footcite` or another cite command, e.g., `\cite`, inside `\footnote`.

Comment: Your example works now, very weird. I have tried \cite inside \footnote, but it only shows "1[1]" in footnote. And if I use \footpartcite in \footnote, in footnote it shows "1([1]National Center for Health Statistics.Accidents or Unintentional Injuries)". So the problem still exists, unfortunately

Comment: @Vivian "another cite command" may also be another self defined cite command. I've now extended the answer by a definition without auto-creation of a footnote. But please read the documentation of the used commands in the `biblatex` manual to understand how it works and what the difference between `\partcite` and `\footpartcite` is.

Comment: Hi, Schweinebacke, I have tried again your script, it works fine in MWE, but with my complete script, it has 2 small problems, in footnote it appears  [author,book name] instead of [1]. And also no [1] appears for footcite. What can be the reason behind this?  Can I send you my complete preamble to check it? Thank you!

Comment: @Vivian: You should make a MWE. You cannot send me your complete code. But I think, you're still using the wrong `style` option loading `biblatex`. As I already explained: To get numeric cite labels you should use a numeric style.

Comment: Hi, I have made a new question regarding my questions with MWE. Could you have a look? Thank you very much! I guess you might be the only person who is able to answer my questions. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346744/how-to-prevent-the-citation-in-footnote-appear-not-in-order