# Citing multiple references with Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want multiple references to appear like [8-10] instead of [8]-[10]. I am using `\usepackage{cite}`. I tried `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}` but box brackets [] are replaced with round brackets () which is also undesirable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make citations appear within square brackets \[ \] instead of parentheses ( )?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82570/how-to-make-citations-appear-within-square-brackets-instead-of-parentheses)

Comment: Yes! It did help